# Multiple (?i) and (?-i) modifiers within js regexp pattern

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, typescript

I am using `nodejs` v8.9.4 and `typescript` v2.6.2. I want to build a `Regexp` that can turn on and off case sensitivity like it do the `(?i)` and `(?-i)` [modifier spans](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) for example in the `.NET` environment.
I want to accomplish something like:

```
let value = 'HelloWorld';
let pattern = '(?i)\\b(' + value + ')\\:|' +
    '(?-i)\\b(' + value.toUpperCase() + '|' + value + ')\\b';
let myRegex = new RegExp(pattern, 'g');

myRegex.test('helloworld');  // returns false
myRegex.test('helloworld:'); // returns true
myRegex.test('HELLOWORLD');  // returns true
myRegex.test('HelloWorld');  // returns true
```

Unfortunately **javaScript does not support modifier spans**.

So I am asking is there a way to build a `Rexep` in javaScript like the `myRegex` of the example above where the `value` is assignable/exchangeable.
Every hint is welcome, thank's in advance.

Comment: Is that the actual way you’re going to use it? With that particular pattern?

Comment: Yes I want to use that particular pattern.

Comment: Can you make two `RegExp`s, then? One with the first part and `'gi'`, one with the second part and `'g'`, `a.test(input) || b.test(input)`?

Comment: In general this would work.  
In my case I will call that regexp pretty often (up to > 60 times per min) and evaluate its `index` to update a document whether it changed. So I think due to performance issues one single regex would be the preferable approach.

Comment: Even `XRegExp` can't handle this. So no one-liner regex solution.

Comment: "up to > 60 times per min" is not "often". Several thousand times per second is often. And you forgot to regex-escape your `value`, that's a bug. Anyway, what is your regex supposed to match, in plain English?

Comment: What is the overall purpose of this? I'm looking at your pattern and can't understand why you wouldn't just use the case-insensitive form for everything.

Comment: Sorry, I do not see where I forgot to escape the `value`. I write a feature for an extension for vscode where the user can set the `value` via the config. My extension detects a document change by hooking the `vscode.workspace.onDidChangeTextDocument` event. When the event fires I search the document with the regex and then colorize all matches by applying a decoration to the corresponding selection. The extension shall support multiple `value`s so there can be multiple regex calls per document change. The event fires on each keystroke.

Comment: You must regex-escape the value before you build a regex from string concatenation. Think about what happens if the value contains `$` or `(` or any of the other characters that have meaning in regex.

Comment: @CAustin I want to highlight custom log level that were set by the user. And I want avoid highlighting occurrences in the log message. For example the user sets the log level to 'Verbose'. Then I want avoid highlighting it in the message "This is *verbose*.". Multiple log file layouts shall be supported.

Comment: @Tomalak now I get it. Thanks for the hint. In the extension code I check for `if (/\w+/g.test(value))` before building that new regexp.

Comment: It's much smarter to use one of the `RegExp.escape()` implementations available. Always, without ifs and buts, whenever you write code that builds regex from strings. There are even node packages that do this, or you simply pick up a one-liner, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Ryan in the comments I split the `Regexp` into two parts. So far I am not facing any performance issues or similar.
Thank's to the guys in the comments for helping out.